# Get nested objects key as joined string

Tags: javascript, formik

Input:

```
{
  "mobile": "Mob # Required",
  "client": [
    undefined,
    null,
    {
      "usergroup": "Required"
    },
    {
      "id": "Required",
      "usergroup": "Required"
    },
    {
      "id": "Required",
      "usergroup": "Required"
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected Output:

```
[
    "mobile", 
    "client.2.usergroup", 
    "client.3.id", 
    "client.3.usergroup", 
    "client.4.id", 
    "client.4.usergroup"
]
```

I am using Formiks FieldArray in my project & the field name in error object is not what is expected.
Object.Keys() doesn't work well for such scenario.

Comment: What are you asking? is this the current output or the expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there are libraries out there to do this for you, but here is what I came up with:

```js
function flattenNestedObject(input, path) {
  path = path || [];

  return Object.keys(input).reduce(function(arr, key) {
    if (input[key] && typeof input[key] === "object") {
      return arr.concat(flattenNestedObject(input[key], path.concat(key)));
    }

    if (typeof input[key] !== 'undefined' && input[key] !== null) {
      return arr.concat((path.concat(key).join(".")));
    }

    return arr;
  }, []);
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-jang-j51dh

The reason `Object.keys` will not work for you is that it doesn't recursively obtain all keys of an object. Also, in your expected output, you don't want all the keys of an object if it contains nested Arrays or Objects.

Comment: Hi @Chris, your soln works fine however when there is **undefined** or **null** in array, it doesn't return expected result. Please check my edited question

Answer (score 2):

You can [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) the keys of the object. If the current key's value is an object, recursively call `getKeys` function with the updated prefix. If not, return the current key with the given provided prefix. Use `flatMap` to get a flattened array of keys instead of nested arrays

```js
const input={mobile:"Mob # Required",client:[{usergroup:"Required"},{id:"Required",usergroup:"Required"},{id:"Required",usergroup:"Required"}]};

const getKeys = (o, prefix = '') =>
  Object.keys(o).flatMap(k =>
    Object(o[k]) === o[k] ? getKeys(o[k], `${prefix}${k}.`) : [prefix + k]
  )

console.log(getKeys(input))
```

If `flatMap` is not supported, you can `reduce` the keys of the object with similar logic

```js
const input={mobile:"Mob # Required",client:[{usergroup:"Required"},{id:"Required",usergroup:"Required"},{id:"Required",usergroup:"Required"}]};

function getKeys(o, prefix = '') {
  return Object.keys(o).reduce((acc, k) => {
    if (Object(o[k]) === o[k])
      acc.push(...getKeys(o[k], `${prefix}${k}.`))
    else
      acc.push(prefix + k)
    return acc;
  }, [])
}

console.log(getKeys(input))
```

Comment: Hi @adiga,
Both soln works fine however when there is undefined or null in array, it doesn't get expected result. Please check my edited question.